# Email list/collection shuffle and pair using underscore/lowdash

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to shuffle an array of objects (name and email address) turning it into a giver -> receiver paired array. Each iteration removes the giver from the receiver's collection so every member of the collection will get a unique partner.

I've used lodash and created a mixin. Sometimes it works, other times it locks up the browser. Perhaps I've got something wrong with the `while` section.

```
_.mixin({
    ldSanta: function (arr) {
        var ret = [],
            emailListCopy = _.assign(arr),
            receiver = {};
        _.times(_.size(emailListCopy), function (i) {
            receiver = arr[i];
            while (receiver === arr[i]) {
                receiver = _.first(_.shuffle(emailListCopy));
            }
            var pair = {
                'giver': arr[i],
                    'receiver': receiver
            };
            ret[i] = _.extend(pair);
            emailListCopy = _.reject(emailListCopy, function (item) {
                return item.name === receiver.name;
            });
        });
        return ret;
    }
});
```

eg. http://jsfiddle.net/ezhsLw16/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop will go on forever when the only person left in `emailListCopy` is the last person in `arr`.

You can get the result you want by doing the following:

1. Shuffle the array. This is the array of givers.
2. Copy it to an array of receivers.
3. Offset the receivers array by 1.
4. Use `zip` to combine the 2 arrays.

By doing this, you don't have to check if the receiver is the same as giver.

```
_.mixin({
    ldSanta: function (arr) {
        if (arr.length < 2) {
            throw "Invalid input, must have at least 2 people";
        }
        var givers = _.shuffle(arr);
        var receivers = _.clone(givers);
        receivers.push(receivers.shift());
        var pairs = _.map(_.zip(givers, receivers), function(pair) {
            return { giver: pair[0], receiver: pair[1] };
        });
        return pairs;
    }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7p7akun/) (JSFiddle is being a bit slow right now)